# How to calculate div width after margin?

Tags: css, sass

I'm working on a responsive website and I'm coming across a problem. I've a div container which width is 100%, and inside it I've 2 div's sidebar and content. Sidebar is set 40% wide  and content is set to 60%.

Now, I want to give 25px space between them and for that I used `margin-left:25px;`.

Now, what will the width of content in % or is there any formula to calcute?

Here is what I am to do - [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yfngfgm7/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change your CSS to use `calc` for the width values, you want to subtract 1/2 the amount of the gap in `px` you want, then add the same amount to the relevant margins:

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/yfngfgm7/2/)

```
.container {
    background:#ccc;
}
.sidebar {
    width:calc(40% - 12.5px);
    margin-right:12.5px;
    background:red;
    height:50px;
    float:left;
}
.content {
    width:calc(60% - 12.5px);
    margin-left:12.5px;
    background:green;
    height:50px;
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: Clever answer, I was working on something entirely different!

Comment: @Gajen - it does work on IE9: http://caniuse.com/#search=calc, dont forget to add these kind of constraints to your questions

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a way to achieve this using `calc` function.

```
.content {
    margin-left:calc(40% + 25px);
}
```

But, the disadvantage is that, `calc` is not cross browser. It won't work in IE.

[**See updated fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/yfngfgm7/1/)

Comment: Is it supported by IE8/9 ?